# How to locate an email address in more than 4,000 data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I am attempting to write an SQL query in SFMC automation studio that will tell me the names of all the data extensions that include one particular email address.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

This is what I have tried

```sql
SELECT EmailAddress
FROM [DE1]
WHERE
EmailAddress = "contact email address"
UNION
Select EmailAddress
FROM [DE 2]
WHERE
EmailAddress = "contact email address"
```

Comment: That query is gonna be gigantic and likely a beast. I would instead recommend using a lookup or a similar scripting solution instead of SQL. This way you can make it more programattic and dynamic instead of static and 'hard coded'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you provide a bit more information so I know what to research? I'm not a coder, so I figure out a lot of things after doing research. Thank you